# Error when deleting a particular event

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

This is the scenario I'm working on. I created a calendar event with the following code:

```
calendar_obj.create(cr,uid,
             {'name' : rec_res.act_ion,
              'user_id' : rec_res.asgnd_to.id,
              'start_date' : lambda *a:datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),
              'stop_date' : rec_res.due_date,
              'allday' : True,
              'partner_ids' : [(6,0, [rec_res.asgnd_to.partner_id.id])]
             },
context=context)
```

It will create an event on the calendar, but I have a problem when I am trying to delete this particular event which was created :

```
File "C:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-11\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\workflow\__init__.py", line 63, in trg_delete
    return WorkflowService.new(cr, uid, res_type, res_id).delete()
  File "C:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-11\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\workflow\service.py", line 37, in new
    return cls(Session(cr, uid), Record(model_name, record_id))
  File "C:\Bitnami\odoo-8.0-11\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-8.0_20150423-py2.7.egg\openerp\workflow\helpers.py", line 13, in __init__
    assert isinstance(record_id, (int, long))
AssertionError
```

`isinstance()` is a function which checks for the real id of the calendar event. As far as I understand, it is not considered as a real calendar event.

**Is there anything that can be done that could solve the above scenario when deleting a calendar event?**

Comment: Did you create it from postgres or from ui?

Comment: created it from my custom module .py file

Comment: Anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Odoo 10 and after some research I have found that CalendarView sends the id of the event to be unlinked as unicode text. That throws the assertion error. This is the code from the CalendarView.

```
remove_event: function(id) {
    var self = this;
    function do_it() {
        return $.when(self.dataset.unlink([id])).then(function() {
            self.$calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
        });
    }
    if (this.options.confirm_on_delete) {
        if (confirm(_t("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?"))) {
            return do_it();
        }
    } else
        return do_it();
},
```

The way I solved the problem was extending the CalendarView and modifying this behaviour. Instead of `self.dataset.unlink([id])` I used `self.dataset.unlink([Number(id)])`. Here is the code.

odoo.define('my_module.calendar', function (require) {
    "use strict";

```
var core = require('web.core');
var calenderView = require('web_calendar.CalendarView');

var _t = core._t;

calenderView.include({
    remove_event: function (id) {
        var self = this;

        function do_it() {
            return $.when(self.dataset.unlink([Number(id)])).then(function () {
                self.$calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
            });
        }

        if (this.options.confirm_on_delete) {
            if (confirm(_t("Are you sure you want to delete this record ?"))) {
                return do_it();
            }
        } else
            return do_it();
    },
});
```

});

I hope this helps and please excuse my english.